# Using variable for column name in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am using SQL Server 2008 and still cannot figure out what's wrong in the stored procedure below:

```
SET @DataDD = 'DataPM'+@DD

SET @SQL = 'UPDATE TraineeMonthlyAttendRecord'+
' SET '+@DataDD+ '="9" '+
'WHERE TraineeID='+@TraineeID+' and RecordID ='+@RecordID

EXEC(@SQL)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just 
 
Replace " with ' doesn't work in this case. I don't know how to deal with the '

Comment: My Mistake, replace `"` with two `'`